# What is the difference between "return view" and "return make:view"?

Tags: php, laravel

I am putting a project together by following this tutorial:
Laravel 8: Basic CRUD Blog Tutorial with Bootstrap
https://www.parthpatel.net/laravel-8-crud-blog-tutorial/

When the PostController index has

```
public function index()
    {   $posts = Post::all();
        return View('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }
```

The exception is `View [posts\index] not found`
but when the return is

```
return view::make('posts.index', compact('posts'));
```

The exception is

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\View' not found
```

Can someone explain the difference? What is the correct syntax for the return

Comment: Read @lagbox 's answer to get familiar with naming convention. Classes should be written with capital starting letter (PascalCase) while functions should be written with starting lower case (camelCase). Also check [here](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices) for good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`view` is a helper function for dealing with the same View Factory as the facade uses:

```
return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
```

Using `View::make` is using the `View` facade as a static proxy to the view factory:

```
return View::make('posts.index', ...);
```

Since you have not aliased the `View` class PHP is assuming when you reference `View` that you mean `View` in the current declared namespace of the file, which is `App\Http\Controllers`, so it is looking for `App\Http\Controllers\View`. You would need to alias this reference for `View` or use its Fully Qualified Class Name:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
...
return View::make(...);
```

Or without the alias:

```
return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::make(...);
```

`view(...)` and `View::make(...)` are both causing `make` to be called on the View Factory to create a new View instance.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Views - Creating and Rendering Views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#creating-and-rendering-views) `view()` `View::make()`